# PostgreSQL: How to get ADD UNIQUE to work

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint

I've truncated my table then added unique:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
ADD UNIQUE (id,loan_type,term,oldestyear)
```

After inserting data, it still duplicates, did I do something wrong?

```
id       |loan_type      |apr   |term|oldestyear|valid_period                     
---------|---------------|------|----|----------|---------------------------------
     8333|auto new       |0.0249|  36|          |["2019-02-26 22:48:07.305304-08",
     8333|auto new       |0.0249|  36|          |["2019-02-26 22:47:38.421624-08",
```

I want id,loan_type,term, & oldest year to be a unique set. oldestyear will be null sometimes but it's  still a unique set despite that.

Comment: What is your actual data structure?

Comment: You allow `null` values in `oldestyear` and one `null` value is never equal to another `null` value - so you can have multiple rows with a null value in that column while the other columns are the same

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I see, so if there's a null value in one of the column, the set can be duplicated, is there a way to have a unique set with nullable columns?

Comment: Are there any "invalid" values for `oldestyear` that can never appear in that column?  Given the name, I would suspect `-1` (or any negative value) to never appear in that column as a valid value

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, any value less than 2000 would be invalid, i see where you're getting at, then just at default value of `-1` and it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can find at least one invalid (not null) value, then you can create a unique index on an expression that converts the `NULL` value to a non-null value so that the comparison treats them as identical:

```
create unique index on mytable (id,loan_type,term,coalesce(oldestyear, -42));
```

Comment: the solution works but i wish there's a way for postgresql to consider null as a value for unique index, this will create workarounds for other processes

Comment: it looks like this doesn't work, it doesn't have constraint, and with constraint, we can't add coalesce unfortunately

Comment: @sojim2: what do you mean with "it doesn't have constraint"? What is "it"

Comment: the table needs a constraint so that I can do an upsert query. For example: `INSERT INTO live_mytable(id, loan_type, apr, term, oldestyear) 
SELECT id, loan_type, apr, term, oldestyear
FROM   imp_mytable
  ON CONFLICT (id,loan_type,term,oldestyear) 
  DO UPDATE SET
     apr = excluded.apr;` Edit this might be easier to read: https://i.imgur.com/81UJ1Zk.png

Comment: @sojim2: you should have mentioned that in your question

Comment: You're right, I'll need to create a question specifying that. Thanks!